# Pymodbus : Listen for changes into holding registers

Tags: python, pymodbus

I have 10 different modbus clients (each client is connected to an automat). I need to listen to each connection and when there is a change in one of the connection i have to store the new value. The values im listeting to are hold into the holding registers.

Here is the current implementation i thought about :

```py
from pymodbus.client import ModbusTcpClient

client = ModbusTcpClient('192.168.5.1')
client.connect()

result = client.read_holding_registers(130,12)

old_value = "".join([chr(code) for code in result.registers])

while client.connect():
    result = client.read_holding_registers(130,12)

    current_value = "".join([chr(code) for code in result.registers])
    
    if current_value!=old_value:
        print("A change has been detected : " + old_value + " to " + current_value)
        old_value = current_value
        
client.close()
```

It works well however as i have 10 differents client and i have to listen to the connection simultaneous which will slow down the perfomances.

My question is is there any better way to get notified for any changes ? Or should i just implement multithreading onto the solution i posted above.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would look at the **Modbus Concurrent Client Example** under Pymodbus Library Examples in their API documentation (https://pymodbus.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.2/examples/concurrent-client.html). The `ConcurrentClient` class operates with a backing worker pool of either processes or threads depending on the user specification for the param `in_process`.

Comment: The example is not up to date so it is not working and tbh i dont really understand what this code is doing as i am new with threading/multiprocess . Do you maybe have a little example for me on how can i reuse this example to my application ?